# How to increase the connection retry period for Jenkins slave nodes

Tags: jenkins

I have a distributed Jenkins setup with many slave nodes.  Sometimes when the master nodes get rebooted, it takes a while for it to come back up and I would lose all slave node.  Is there a way to set the retry period for the slave nodes?  I would like to increase it to say one hour, or keep retrying indefinitely.

Comment: As far as I know, there is no way to set the slave connection retry interval without changing the source code.

Answer (score 0):

According to [Launching slave.jar from from console](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Launching+slave.jar+from+from+console) it's supposed to happen the other way round:

> *slave.jar is meant to be launched by Jenkins. [...] slave.jar is **not** meant to initiate a connection to the master on its own*

There's also an option to [Write your own script to launch Jenkins slaves](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Distributed+builds#Distributedbuilds-WriteyourownscripttolaunchJenkinsslaves).